# What are the "host record" options available?

Tags: dns

When setting up a new A Record / Host Record there's an option to enter the "host", and then one to enter the "IP". What are the options available for host?

I've seen www, @, *... are there others? I have read many tutorials about A Records, and yet every single one of them fail to explain the "host" part of the record.

I understand what www and * does, but what about @?

Answer (score 1):

The "host" name is the domain the A record links to. Type @ to point the record directly to the domain name.

Comment: Are there other types? Wildcards that can be used? Is there any documentation on the types? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to know what are my options.

Comment: If you want to know about DNS records, try this and see if it answers your questions: https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090?hl=en

Comment: I know how to set them up and how it works, but nowhere it lists all the available options that can go under the "host" column. That's all I wanted to know, if there are other specific options that can go there? Such as @ and www. I guess there isn't.

Comment: @gdaniel You can use 1 to 64 characters, allowed characters are a-z, 0-9 and hyphen.